# How to represent alternative and sequential tasks?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am experimenting with hierarchical task planning (in python) and I would like to have functions which return lists of tasks. I need to differentiate between alternative paths and sequential tasks. My current approach is to return a list of lists of tasks, e.g.:

```
def travel():
    return [ [call_yellow_cab, ride_yellow_cab, pay_driver],
             [call_limousine,  ride_limousine,  pay_driver] ]
```

The sequential tasks would be call.., ride.., pay_driver. The first and second lists would represent alternative task sequences (cab or limousine).

As '*Explicit is better than implicit*' according to 'The Zen of Python' I am curious if there is a more explicit way to differentiate between the alternative tasklists and the sequential tasks within.
Or is my approach not that bad as '*Simple is better than complex.*' ?

Comment: I think your current `list`-of-`list`s approach (outer list holds paths, inner lists hold tasks) is fine. You could make it *slightly* more explicit by using a `set` (unordered, suggesting equal alternatives) of `tuple`s (ordered, suggesting a strict sequence), but that might be too subtle!

Comment: *(it would also require your tasks to be hashable)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that naming intermediate results often provides semantic clarity to the humans reading it later, even if it doesn't change the end result.  Like focusing a lens, sometimes the proper point is easiest to see by taking it to extremes then backing off.  The extreme version of explicitness is:

```py
def travel():
    yellow_cab_sequence = [call_yellow_cab, ride_yellow_cab, pay_driver]
    limousine_sequence  = [call_limousine,  ride_limousine,  pay_driver]
    alternatives = [yellow_cab_sequence, limousine_sequence]
    return alternatives
```

This makes it abundantly explicit you are returning alternative sequences, although I would probably back off from this point a little and merge the last two lines.  It also makes it easy to see opportunities to create function calls to reduce duplication or better separate abstraction levels, perhaps `yellow_cab_sequence()` or even `ground_transportation_sequence("yellow cab")`.

You could also add clarity by choosing a name for the function such as `travel_alternatives`.

On the other hand, if your code truly stays as simple as your example, it's clear enough as-is.  Just keep the technique in mind as the complexity grows of explicitly naming intermediate results or splitting them into functions.